# Python-Docx-Template PackageNotFoundError

Tags: python, tkinter, python-docx

I want to convert tkinter app to executable by cx_freeze or PyInstaller [TRIED BOTH].. And my app depends on python-docx and python-docx-template as well.. but when I click on button all process occurs correctly but wps (using linux) does not open .docx file with error.  I can share code which is more than 4 files and main file is upto 600 lines and depends on other files.

1. main.py -- Contain Main menu which user has to input entries then click on a button Submit
2. UCT_fun.py -- Submit button refers to a function file named UCT_fun.py which contains my Template file (Python-Docx-Template) which has to populate entries by user input
3. When clicked on button following error happened.

`docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at '/home/badshah/Work/Tkinter/GSK-Project/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.8/templates/include/Doc0.docx'`

I have tried to find the path, abspath, relpath and many stackoverflow, discord helps. I can share each try by demand if someone really understands my situation.

I am stuck from 4 days.

Comment: This error from `python-docx` means it's not finding a `.docx` file to load. I expect the file in question is a starting template file of some sort. Usually this means these "data" files are not being included in your "bundle" and need to be mentioned in the bundler (e.g. PyInstaller) configuration file. Not much more than a hint, but hopefully points in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for commenting.. Actually I got some clue because I was including files in wrong dir.. Which is somehow I am able to fix the issue..